# Can't Find Type

Tags: powershell, class

I'm getting started with PowerShell classes, and I'm trying to follow this brief tutorial using ISE:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-5-create-simple-class/

Here's the sample code from that page:

```
Class Car
{
    [String]$vin
    static [int]$numberOfWheels = 4
    [int]$numberOfDoors
    [datetime]$year
    [String]$model
}
```

and here's the command to run:

```
$Chevy = New-Object Car
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> New-Object : Cannot find type [Car]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

This seems odd. Shouldn't PowerShell be able to find this class? ISE IntelliSense can't find it either.

What do I have to do to get this to run?

[image]

Comment: I would focus on the error you're getting when you hit F5. Not being able to create a new instance of a class you never loaded isn't a real issue.

Comment: @MikeFrank ~ I'm just going by what the author of the tutorial is doing. A [screen shot](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/29/2019/02/hsg-9-1-15-01.jpg) there shows him at the PS prompt, instantiating the new object that he's defined in code as a class. Why ISE can find the class for him but not for me is a mystery to me.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I think it's implied that code from the editor pane has to be run in order to work.

Comment: @MikeFrank ~ Ah, OK—I get you now. But by this time I've managed to make it to a point in my project where I can do without the functionality. I needed to get some JSON syntax worked out, and now that I've got the basics I can stub in the rest of the JSON text file by hand. Copying and pasting the classes at the prompt got me by. I'll be switching to VSCode for the next one, so it's probably not worth trying to figure this out. I appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Here is  a decent set of quick videos / walk-thru training on PowerShell Classes by PowerShell MVP Trevor Sullivan …https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=PowerShell+classes+trevor+Sullivan … that is if you prefer the guided video learning approach

Comment: @postanote ~ Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you're trying to instantiate your `Car` class from the ISE's integrated *console*, whereas the class *definition* is contained in a *script tab*.

Therefore, **you must *run* the code in the script tab *first*** in order to define the class, in the simplest case by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

---

On a general note, it is **worth switching from the PowerShell ISE to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) as the editor for PowerShell code, because that's where all future development effort will go; **if you're planning to work with PowerShell *Core***, the multi-platform edition, **the ISE isn't even an option**.

Answer (score 1):

When you write custom code like class or functions, the shell has to be aware of those declarations in order to use it.
When you start powershell, it comes with pre-loaded Types and cmdLets. This is why you can use commands like :
`get-command`
or build a string
`[string]$mystring`

In order to use your class you will have to run you class declaration using F5. Then you can instanciate this object in this shell :
`$mycar = New-Object Car`

If you want to use this class in multiple scripts, you can save it as a .ps1 file and run it before to use it in your script :
`. <filepath>\<filename>.ps1`

```
. C:\Car.ps1
$myCar = New-Object Car
```

[Use you Car class in the shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNKa8.png)

Or you can write a module and import it in your script:

```
import-module <filePath>\myscript.ps1
$myCar = New-Object Car
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It turned out that my ISE instance had some sort of temporary internal corruption; I was getting `An error occurred while creating the pipeline` whenever I pressed F5 to run the code. Because of this, I mistakenly thought I'd hit a dead end. Once I restarted ISE, though, everything ran smoothly. I appreciate the tip. +1